# cannot get hibernate session in child threads running bulk db operations

Tags: java, multithreading, hibernate, session

I am trying to split up a bulk db inserts and run them in groups using worker threads. However, sessionFactory.getCurrentSession() from within the child threads produces: "java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread". How can I set up to obtain valid current sessions within the child threads?

```
@Configuration
```

@EnableTransactionManagement
public class MockDbContext {

```
@Bean
@Autowired
public HibernateTransactionManager getHibernateTransactionManager( SessionFactory sessionFactory ){
    HibernateTransactionManager manager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
    manager.setSessionFactory( sessionFactory );
    return manager;
}

@Autowired
@Bean 
public static MyRepository getRepository( SessionFactory factory ) {
    MyRepository repository = new MyRepository();
    ReflectionTestUtils.setField( repository, "sessionFactory", factory );
    return repository;
}

@Autowired
@Bean
public SessionFactory getSessionFactory( BasicDataSource dataSource, @Qualifier( "hibernateProperties" ) Properties hibernateProperties ) {
    return new LocalSessionFactoryBuilder( dataSource )
        .scanPackages( "com.hibernate.components" )
            .addProperties( hibernateProperties )
                .buildSessionFactory();
}

@Bean
public BasicDataSource getBasicDataSource(){
    BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName( driverClassName );
    dataSource.setUrl( url );
    dataSource.setUsername( user );
    dataSource.setPassword( pass );
    return dataSource;
}

@Bean( name = "hibernateProperties" )
public Properties getHibernateProperties(){
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.setProperty( "hibernate.cache.region.factory_class", "org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory" );
    properties.setProperty( "hibernate.cache.use_query_cache", "true" );
    properties.setProperty( "hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache", "true" );
    properties.setProperty( "hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect" );
    properties.setProperty( "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create" );
    properties.setProperty( "hibernate.show_sql", "true" );
    return properties;
}

@Bean 
public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
    return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
}

@Bean
public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor getPersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor(){
    return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
}
```

}

```
@Repository
```

public class MyRepository {

```
@Autowired
SessionFactory sessionFactory

protected Session getSession(){
    return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
}

public Record findById( long id ){
    return ( Record ) getSession().get( Record.class, id );
}

@Transactional
public Collection<Record> findByMultipleIds( Set<Long> ids ){
    Collection<Record> records = new ArrayList<Record>();
    List<Future<Record>> futures = new ArrayList<Future<Record>>();
    ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool( 10 ); 
    for( int i = 0; i < ids.size(); ++i ){
        futures.add( pool.submit( new MyCallable<Record>( ids.get( i ))));
    }
    for( Future<Record> future : futures ) {
        records.add( future.get() );
    }
    return records;
}

private class MyCallable<Record> implements Callable<Record>{
    private long id;
    private MyCallable( long id ){
        this.id = id;
    }   
    @Override
    public Record call(){
        return findById( id );
    }   
}
```

}

```
@RunWith( SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class )
```

@ContextConfiguration( loader = AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class, classes = MockDbContext.class )
public class MyRepositoryTest {

```
@Rule
public ExpectedException exception = ExpectedException.none;

private Record expected;

@Autowired
private MyRepository repository;

public void testFindByIds() throws NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException, IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException{
    exception.expect( HibernateException.class );
    exception.expectMessage( "Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread" );
    expected.findByMultipleIds( new HashSet<Long>( Arrays.asList( new long[]{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10} ))); 
}

public void setUp(){
   expected = new Record();
}

public void tearDown(){
    expected = null;
}
```

}

Comment: A transaction can not be shared by several threads. Each thread needs to start and commit its own transaction (by calling a transactional bean method).

Comment: Adding to what JB Nizet said above. If you're doing batch processing, it is usually recommended to use a [StatelessSession](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/api/org/hibernate/StatelessSession.html), as otherwise you might encounter memory problems, as Hibernate will keep a copy of each object you have queried in the 1st level cache (I'm assuming batch processing = process large number of records).

Comment: Thank you, guys. I found out last night that hibernate maintains separate session for transaction(s) per thread. Although, hibernate session for transactions within the main thread could simply be obtained with getCurrentSession, same cannot be said for any additional child thread

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I ended up adding a small class autoclass to create new session inside the child thread and close the session as soon as the child thread exits.

```
@Repository
```

public class MyRepository {

```
@Autowired
SessionFactory sessionFactory

protected Session getSession(){
    return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
}

public Record findById( long id ){
    return ( Record ) getSession().get( Record.class, id );
}

public Collection<Record> findByMultipleIds( Set<Long> ids ){
    Collection<Record> records = new ArrayList<Record>();
    List<Future<Record>> futures = new ArrayList<Future<Record>>();
    ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool( 10 ); 
    for( int i = 0; i < ids.size(); ++i ){
        futures.add( pool.submit( new MyCallable<Record>( ids.get( i ))));
    }
    for( Future<Record> future : futures ) {
        records.add( future.get() );
    }
    return records;
}

private class TemporarySession implements AutoCloseable{
    private Session session;
    protected TemporarySession(){
        create();
    }
    protected Session getSession(){
        return session;
    }
    protected void create(){
        session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    }
    protected void destroy(){
        session.flush();
        session.clear();
        session.close();
    }
    @Override
    public void close(){
        destroy();
    }
}

private class MyCallable<Record> implements Callable<Record>{
    private long id;
    private MyCallable( long id ){
        this.id = id;
    }
    @Override   
    public Record call(){
        try( TemporarySession tSession = new TemporarySession() ){
            return tSession.get( Record.class, id );
        }
    }   
}
```

}